# Mosfet control Rds on , and Vgs

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, reverse-polarity, powermosfet

I want to know how to calculate Vgs , assuming load current Id is constant , Vd = voltage of battery is constant , and fet is operating in thermal stability region , so there is no thermal runnawy , connecting gate to ground leads us having

[image]

**Vgs = - Vs** , so we need to calculate Vs

**Vds = Vd - Vs = V battery - Vs = Ids Rds**

so how to measure Rds ? i know it is dependent on temperature

but measuring temperature in thermal stability will be difficult , as temp increase Ids decreases so temp decrease until certain point so no change after that , so the temp that it will settle at is what matters

**can i assume max Rds to know min Vgs ?
is there anoghter approach to control mosfet ?**

---

update :

after reading :

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_Linear_Mode_Operation_Safe_Operation_Diagram_MOSFETs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433e30e4bf013e3646e9381200

i know that there is safe operating area,

assuming Ron on limit i did these calculations below

**is it right? or should i assume that Vgs = 10 Volt at max Rds

when to use Rds on limit and Max power line limit ?**

[image]

---

update 2 :

[image]

Comment: As shown, your MOSFET will act like a forward biased diode, not like a transistor.  (HINT: Note the orientation of the MOSFET's body diode.)  If you want the MOSFET to act like a transistor, you must connect the source to the 30V supply and the drain to the load.

Comment: @Jim , thanks for your reply ,actually i dont know about making mosfet act as transistor , but i have tested this circuit and it actually works fine for reverse polarity protection , so i wanted to just make right calculations .

Comment: Vgs = 10 volts Ahmed and not -Vs. Vs is nearly 30 volts at instant of power supplied.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for your reply , well i have updated my question , asking about is my calculations wrong and i have to assume vgs = 10 , and when to assume Rds on limit , and max power limit .

Comment: Have you looked in the data sheet to see what Rds(on) is for 10 volts on the gate-source?

Comment: Rdson is related to the heat dissipation, as the mosfet is no switching, the temperature rising is function of  the rdson, RMS current, thermal resistances, you can find a lot about it. Safe operated area is mainly used for inrush current, when you have a transient for a short period of time to make sure the mosfet can handle it.

Comment: @Andyaka  ok i will look right now

Comment: @Delphesk  in pdf that i attached it says:

Comment: the RDS(on) of the
MOSFET is completely irrelevant when calculating the power dissipation. The power dissipation in the MOSFET
depends only on the voltage drop across the MOSFET and the current flow: Pdiss=VDS  IDS

Comment: @Delphesk i have added photo to my question

Comment: @Andyaka i have noticed a linear relation  between Tj and Rdon when Vgs = -10 volt , so  for Rds limit line i have linear relation so i have to assume Vgs = -10 v in my calculations right ?

Comment: @Delphesk  also i think mosfet is non linear device is not like resistor so power cant be calculated as I square * R but i*v

Comment: @Delphesk i dont think temp is function of Rds its opposite  , and this is comes to Temperature coefficient ,   where cases for mosfet it can be postive negative or zero , which means if temp increase Current will decrease or increase or  no change , so the driving force is Temperature not resistance , actually resistance is just ratio between voltage and current , and it 's better to be Z  impedance not R cauz its not resistor .

Comment: @Andyaka is my calculation right except that Vgs , so i have to recalculate with same steps ?

Comment: Power to the load : PLoad = V*I-PD, PD=Rdson *I^2, Rdson is function of Vgs and junction temperature, Vgs is clamped at 10V by the zener (choose worst case 125°C) Tjunction=Tambient+(PD * Rthja).If the temperature is getting too hot your switch will break, so make sure you choose the right rated part to don't reach the maximum temperature admissible.

Comment: @Delhesk thanks for your reply sir ,well u are saying that power dissipation calculated with i squared * Rds , but according to the pdf its V*I , so what do u think? I have searched for this subject and found this : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130527/difference-between-i2r-and-v2-r-and-vi-for-measuring-power-p

Comment: No, i think you get it wrong, Rdson*I^2 is the conduction losses in the mosfet. The Output power is either Vout^2/Rload or Vout * Iout ( ohm's law ).

Comment: @Delphesk  if that so why in pdf it says  rds ss irrelevant when calculating power dissipation

Comment: Your first question is related to the reverse polarity protection, your update 2 is talking about a fan controller which control the speed of the motors if i am not wrong, we are talking about different thing then.

Comment: @Delphesk yes u are right but after considering linear operation its easy to consider saturation where voltage at gate is constant